# Unable to install RVM using curl

Tags: 12.04, ruby, rvm, curl

When i try to install the rvm using curl it displays the following message:-

```
vverma@l-vverma:~$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try again, but replace the "get.rvm.io" part with `raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer` ? it's the same script, just takes out some potential DNS problems on rvm's end.