# installing rvm in 12.04 ubuntu which is on virtualbox

Tags: bash, virtualbox, proxy, ruby

I have tried a lot of methods but cant get this done. I am trying to install rvm on 12.04 ubuntu. There has been many problems in past like this and I have referred as much as I can and still nothing is working for me. Even wirting `sudo` in front of these doesnt work.
What I tried are the following:

1. `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`
2. `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
3. `curl -L raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable`

**I am able to ping each of them though.**

Everytime I get the this error:
`couldn't connect to host`
OR
`network is unreachable`

it looks like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I already tried the solution proposed in [Unable to install RVM using curl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209503/unable-to-install-rvm-using-curl)

I am using NAT adapter for internet and wired connection. I do not have any proxies enabled and all my firewalls are disabled in my hosting OS which is windows.

My proxy settings for ubuntu are set to `none`

But still I am not able to get this done.

Can somebody tell me what could be the problem and how to fix it.
Is it something to do with guest additions because i don't have that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to reach get.rvm.io. 
You could try running curl in verbose mode and expect some similar output.

Look for ***Connected to*** string. 
If this is not visible and the command is stuck at ***About to connect()*** string, you can be assured you have a connectivity problem from your VM.

$ curl -Iv get.rvm.io
* Rebuilt URL to: get.rvm.io/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x16fef90
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x16fef90) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* **About to connect() to get.rvm.io port 80 (#0)**
*   Trying 97.107.133.48...
**Connected to get.rvm.io (97.107.133.48) port 80 (#0)**

> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
>   Host: get.rvm.io
>   Accept: */*
>
> < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>   * Server nginx/1.6.0 is not blacklisted
>   < Server: nginx/1.6.0
>   Server: nginx/1.6.0
>   < Date: Sun, 25 May 2014 07:48:40 GMT
>   Date: Sun, 25 May 2014 07:48:40 GMT
>   < Content-Type: text/html
>   Content-Type: text/html
>   < Content-Length: 184
>   Content-Length: 184
>   < Connection: keep-alive
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   < Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer
>   Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer

- Connection #0 to host get.rvm.io left intact

Comment: i got the same error with this too.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error ?

Comment: now i am not able to ping the address as well

Comment: connection timeout

Comment: network is unreachable then  it shows "success" and "couldnot connect to host"

Comment: I tried to ping get.rvm.io i got 100% package loss

Comment: Looks like, there is no network connectivity from your VM. You to resolve that first. Have a look [here](http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-one.html)

Comment: but ping was working few mins ago

Comment: ok..but i am able to ping google.com

Comment: do i still need to set VM? @Garfield

Comment: Why dont we troubleshoot this in IRC ? Join #ubuntu channel on https://webchat.freenode.net/

Comment: yeah sure..let do that.

Comment: have u joined it?

Comment: Yes. You can find me there with other people :). Just mention this post in the channel.

Comment: what is the channel name?

Comment: its asking me to make an account

Answer (score 0):

RVM can be installed in ubuntu with the repository [**ppa:rvm/ppa**](https://launchpad.net/~rvm/+archive/ppa). You dont need to implement difficult compilation methods.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

Comment: is this for installing ruby?